# How can I filter `git cherry` output?

Tags: bash, git, filter, version, cherry-pick

I ran the below command,

```
git cherry main dev
```

The output for above command is like,

```
+ d86f3e25f42b546af008b774c2649d585cc48310
- 1d90a12b91b461f857eb373d69372a2864b9e651
+ 4194aa6d206225242e881d2128e59981b8826eeb
```

I want to see only commits which are not yet cherry-picked. *i.e. (+ signed sha only)*.

Expected output,

```
+ d86f3e25f42b546af008b774c2649d585cc48310
+ 4194aa6d206225242e881d2128e59981b8826eeb
```

**How can I do so?**

Comment: `git cherry main dev | grep '^+[[:space:]].*$`  but are you sure `git` can't do that on it's own?

Comment: At least git cherry has no option to do that filtering.

Comment: @Jetchisel, `grep -e '^+'` will do the job (see the actual expected output OP wants). Btw, does `git log --oneline main..dev` shows anything meaningful?

Comment: @Oandriy, `git log --oneline main..dev` does not help. It shows all three commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it :

```
git cherry main dev | grep '^+'
```

Regards!